# How to handle the dependency management of a complex system implemented in Python

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pypi, software-distribution

We develop a system that includes a lot of different Python scripts and modules. Some are deployed to a self-hosted PyPI and some are simple packaged into a zip file (stored in a self-hosted Artifactory). Finally, there is another application (not developed by us), that uses some of our Python scripts as plugins. So, the dependency graph is rather complex for a python environment, I guess. The following snippet should explain the graph:

```
Script (own, zip package)
    Module (own, pypi)
        Module (external, pypi)
Module (own, pypi)
    Module (external, pypi)
```

This is just an example, in reality, there are much more dependencies. But in the end, it is a mix of zip packaged and pypi packaged Pyhton scripts and modules. The dependencies of the pypi modules are managed via setuptools install_requires parameter in the setup.py. But the dependencies of the zip packaged scripts are managed via a self-implemented configuration and install script.

At the end, we have our install script that creates one virtual environment and installs all dependencies in it. Either via pip or simple download the zip files and put it in the right directory. But honestly, that feels a little bit weird and we are not sure if this is the right (pythonic) way to go.

We already searched couple of days through the internet but found no answer. It also seems, that it is very uncommon to have such a complex system implemented in Python? So, the final question is: is our approach the right one or is there not really "the right way"? Or is our approach completely wrong?

Comment: Why don't you install your own package with pip (or poetry)? Create the `setup.py` at the root of your project and do `pip install .`

Comment: Any reason not to use a private index for all private dependencies and just use pip's built-in dependency resolver?

Comment: Yes, that's a really good point. We startet to convert all Scripts and even non-Python stuff like configurations to pypi packages and put them into our private pypi repository. That enables us to handle everything via pip. Thanks a lot to Pynchia and @DustinIngram. I will respond with the result of our tests.